# CSS ID vs CLASS while using addClass

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

I am creating a File Drop Effect where when a file is dragged the border color should change.

```
#upload-photo {
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border-style: dashed;
    border:4px dashed #c0c0c0;
}
.upload-photo-border {
    border:4px solid #999;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="upload-photo">Drop photo here to upload.</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
.............
    dragOver: function() {
        // user dragging files over #dropzone
                $("#upload-photo").addClass("upload-photo-border");
                $('#upload-photo').css('width', '100px');
    },
..........
```

The Border Color still wont change on adding the required class. Not sure if am doing something wrong.

Comment: .addClass("upload-photo-border");  may be? That's what your code is saying: there's no upload-photo-hover class is there?

Comment: should the class in the jQuery be: 'upload-photo-hover' or 'upload-photo-border'?

Comment: sorry i was playing with the name to make sure thats not right. i added !important and now its working :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Make your class selector more specific. For example:

```
#upload-photo.upload-photo-border{
    border:4px solid #999;
}
```

As a general rule, remember that ID selectors are more specific than class selectors, which are in turn more specific than tag name selectors.

Additionally, the more parts present in your selector, the more specific it becomes.

Comment: +1, a very useful answer. Personally didn't know about specificity, always used to solve that issue with `important`. Thanks!

Comment: so the class and id will be assigned to the same div ?

Comment: @MorganWilde `!important` is a trick I used to use a lot when I felt too lazy to track down exactly why a certain rule was preferred to another one, but it makes your CSS pretty unmaintainable.

Comment: @HarshaMV The class and ID aren't being changed. All this is doing is applying the rule to all elements that have both an id of `upload-photo` and a class name of `upload-photo-border`

Answer (score 2):

The css id rules are more strength than class rules. You can write like this

```
#upload-photo.upload-photo-border {
    border:4px solid #999;
}
```

or use !important

```
.upload-photo-border {
    border:4px solid #999 !important;
}
```